# Do upper semi continuous functions on a compact set admit a "modulus of semicontinuity"?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

When considering an upper semicontinuous function on a compact set, I am curious about whether the following property holds. Could you give me the proof of the following property?

Let $\Omega$ be an open bounded set in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $u\in\mbox{USC}(\overline{\Omega})$. Then there exists a non-negative concave function $m:[0,1]\rightarrow [0,\infty)$ such that $m(0)=0$ and 
$$\sup\limits_{B_{r}(x)}u(y)-u(x)\leq m(r),\quad \forall x\in\overline{\Omega},\quad 0\leq r\leq 1.$$

---

Note that if $u$ is *continuous*, then such $m$ exists: namely, the modulus of continuity of $u$. In this case we have $|u(y)-u(x)|\le m(r)$. The above one-sided inequality says that $m$ acts like a "modulus of semicontinuity".

Answer (score 1):

This is false. Let $\Omega$ be the unit ball, and let $u=0$ everywhere except at the center, where $u=1$. This is an upper semicontinuous function. But for all $r>0$ and all $x\in B_{r/2}(0)\setminus \{0\}$ we have 
$$
\sup_{B_r(x)} u(y)  = 1 
$$
hence $m(r)=1$ for $r>0$.